# Best puzzles of 2017 Q3 (July - September)?

Tags: discussion, best-of

*This question is part of the [best-puzzle award series](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of).*

---

> ### What are your nominations for the best puzzles, here on Puzzling.SE, of the third quarter (July / August / September) 2017?

Suggested guidelines for nomination:

- Nominate each individual puzzle in a separate answer, so they can be upvoted/downvoted separately.
- No more than 3 nominations per person.
- Don't nominate your own puzzles.
- Before you nominate a puzzle, check to see if someone else has already nominated it. If they have, then add to that nomination as a comment (or edit it) instead of nominating the same puzzle again.
- **In your nomination, explain what it is that (in your opinion) makes the nominated puzzle such a good one.**

---

> Some lists to help jog your memory (your nomination doesn't have to be from these lists):
>
> - Algorithmically selected "best of":
>
>   - [***Popular puzzles***, both in score and in vote to view ratio, from 2017 Q3](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/509699/popular-puzzles-quaterly?year=2017&month=7#query-results)
>   - [Well received puzzles ***you may have missed*** from 2017 Q3](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/509700/puzzles-you-may-have-missed-quaterly?year=2017&month=7#query-results)
> - Best by votes/views:
>
>   - [Questions with the most ***votes*** from 2017 Q3](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106579?StartDate=2017/07/01#query-results)
>   - [Questions with the most ***views*** from 2017 Q3](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106705?StartDate=2017/07/01#query-results)
>   - [Questions with the highest-voted ***answers*** from 2017 Q3](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106709?StartDate=2017/07/01#query-results)

---

Meta-meta issues:

- Is this kind of thing allowed on SE?

  - Yes, [Photography SE](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/weekly-featured-image-ongoing-contest) and [Sci-fi/Fantasy SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3142/31394) do something very similar.
- What's the point?

  - To highlight and encourage good practice in a way that goes beyond upvotes.
  - To work towards building a 'hall of fame' of some of the best puzzles on the site (perhaps to reside on a future puzzling.SE blog) - think of it as our 'greatest hits album'.
  - To prompt members to put forward their own reflections on what makes a high-quality puzzle.

Answer (score 18):

## [A puzzle in 140 characters](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/54165/a-puzzle-in-140-characters) by stacksfiller

This puzzle ticks all the boxes that a good multipart/meta puzzle should:

- **Individually interesting sub-parts** - in this puzzle there are many micro-puzzles, which whilst incredibly compact are still intriguing and satisfying in their own right
- **Partial self-validation** - each part resolves to a simple, short English word, making it fairly clear that you've reached the correct partial answer, and can help get you across the line when you're only 90% sure on something (no magic numbers or imgur urls), similarly the meta helps to back fill sub-puzzles if you get stuck on one or two of them
- **Coherency when bringing the parts together for the final solution** - the final meta puzzle is very well constructed here, with a set of sub-parts that all use the same method to extract specific pairs of letters to produce the solution, which would most definitely not have been an easy task
- **A theme that somehow ties things together** - the presentation here is not just a gimmick, but ties directly to the solution, which is not only amusing and clever, but provides a satisfying sense of conclusion

And all this crammed into a single 140 character sequence! Fantastically thought out and polished puzzle, whose size belies the amount of design time that clearly went into it.

<sub><del>(and it's score is only just short of 140, so go up vote if you haven't already)</del></sub>

<sub>...we did it PSE! Now stop voting. <sup>(but don't really)<sup>(but really do)</sup></sup></sub>

Comment: Shame on me. This post made me aware that I haven't been watching PuzzlingSE for a whole quarter now! I really hope more things get "hand-picked" here. Oh, and people doing that should possible revisit Q2 as well. Only 1 entry for 3 months ? I'm sure we had more HQ stuff. Maybe people don't visit META that offen anymore?

Answer (score 2):

## [More Nodes & Tunnels - The Tower](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/53463/more-nodes-tunnels-the-tower) by [BreakingMyself](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/37821/breakingmyself)

What is not to like at a puzzle like this?

- The task is clear and challenging but *doable* for beginners
- Visuals are clean and nice

If you like mazes, give it a try!